# JS/ import a class method into another class

Tags: javascript, class, es6-class

Is it possible to import a method from one class into another in JS?

Say I have a class `A`

```
class A {
    someMethod(parameters){
        // some code here
    }
}
```

and I want to be able to alias that method in another class `B`, i.e.

```
aInstance = new A();
class B {
    anotherMethod = aInstance.someMethod;

}
```

I know this doesn't work, but is it a syntax issue, or is it not possible to pass methods between class objects like this?

Comment: `aInstance.someMethod();`

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be to define a `static` method on class `A` and then use it in `B` (without instantiating `A`).

```js
class A {
  static someMethod() {
    console.info("Called via B!");
  }
}

class B {
  anotherMethod(...args) {
    return A.someMethod(...args);
  };
}

const b = new B();

b.anotherMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are attempting to do is not invalid syntax, though it is not the right way to do it.

First thing is you may have meant

```
aInstance = new A();
class B {
  anotherMethod = aInstance.someMethod;
}
```

which would technically work, but it's not the best way as you may have problems when using `this` inside the function.

What you could to to prevent issues with `this` is use an arrow function

```
class A {
  someMethod = (parameters) => {
    //... some code
  }
}

class B {
  anotherMethod = new A().someMethod;
}
```

Another way to go about this problem, depending on what exactly you want to achieve is to have a function exported instead of having it as a class member.

```
// A.js
export const someMethod = (parameters) => {

}

// B.js
import {someMethod} from './A';

class B extends A {
  anotherMethod = someMethod;
}
```

Finally, one more thing to consider depending on the relationship between the two classes, is if it would be wise to use inheritance

```
class A {
  someMethod = (parameters) => {
    //... some code
  }
}

class B extends A {
  anotherMethod = (...parameters) => {
    super.someMethod.apply(this, parameters);
  }
}
```

Though that way it would still be possible to call `someMethod` on an instance of `B`.

Comment: See above: I'm getting `Unexpected token =` when I try to use `anotherMethod = new A().someMethod;`

Comment: Could you please post the actual code you tried? I'm testing this in the console and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use the instance:

```
anotherMethod = aInstance.someMethod;
```

instead of

```
anotherMethod = A.someMethod;
```

Comment: Getting `Unexpected token =` -- does this mean that I need to have this set in my constructor method?